# google fusion table select in from another table not working

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to select some rows based on row values from some other table but its not working. I have tried something like this

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: '\'Geocodable address\'',
      from: '1m9CwnJrCfWNHCEQQkxqcQBzp-dA-S9KB8vLTpCrv',
      where: 'ZCTA5CE10 in (select zip from 1V6aWLW-CEw2hRcPSzom1b9-Op6PS1ZQiyCH3GIRI)'
    },
    styles: [{
      polygonOptions: _defaultStyle
    }]
  });
  layer.setMap(map);
```

Its ignoring the where clause and drawing all rows on map. How to fix it?

Comment: You need to compute the second level select outside of the FusionTableLayer query.

Comment: how outside? The result for second level is quite huge, if will add the result only then it will failed due to longer length.